# to check wheather a number is even or odd without using loop

Tags: java

```
class bool {

    public static void main(String arg[]) {

        int n = 2;

        boolean b = (n % 2 == 0);

        System.out.print(b);

        String s = String.valueOf(b);

        switch (s) {

            case true:

                System.out.println("even");

                break;

            default:
                System.out.println("odd");

                break;

        }


}
```

i am getting problm of incompetible type
plz help i have to print a number to be odd or even without loop.

Comment: you don't need a loop. You have already solved it, just open your eyes and don't do useless conversions... What do you think the following line means? boolean b=(n%2==0);

Comment: Why are you converting your boolean to a string before using it in the switch statement? Your switch statement is checking for true or false, which are boolean values, so you don't need to convert it to a string.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting incompatible types because you are attempting to use a `boolean` case label `true` when the switch expression is a `String` `s`.  You don't even need the `String`; just use `b` itself.  `boolean`s aren't allowed as switch expressions, but you don't need a `switch` if all you have is a `boolean`.  Just use an `if` statement.

Answer (score 1):

The variable used in the case in a String however in each case you are using a boolean:

```
public static void main(final String arg[]) {
    final int n = 2;
    final boolean b = n % 2 == 0;
    System.out.print(b);
    System.out.println(b ? "even" : "odd");
}
```

Comment: here i dont want to use if else statement

Comment: I modified the post to change from if to switch

Comment: @rafalopez79 you can't switch on boolean.

Comment: @rafalopez79 Now it's correct. I'm giving you a +1 for the tenacity :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't switch on a `String` value in Java 6 or below. What you want is

```
if (b) {
   System.out.println("even");
} else {
   System.out.println("odd");
}
```

`String s=String.valueOf(b);` is useless.

Also consider using more descriptive names for your variables. `b` gives no information about what this variable *means* in the code logic. `isEven` for example is a much better name, see how the code is more readable now:

```
if (isEven) {
   System.out.println("even");
} else {
   System.out.println("odd");
}
```

---

> i want to do this without any if else and without any loop

Strange requirement... It just makes the code less readable and more bloated. Usually you want `switch` for when there are more than 2 possible values. Anyway:

```
final int result = n % 2;
switch (result) {
case 0:
    System.out.println("even");
    break;
default:
    System.out.println("odd");
}
```

Comment: @Alboz I'm anwsering about why the error, which is the actual question. Anyway I expanded my answer.

Comment: i want to do this without any if else and without any loop

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand question correctly, and from your comments it looks like you do not want to use if/else or switch - you can opt for using a wrapper.

```
IntWrapper wrapper = new IntWrapper(n);
System.out.println("Is Even ? "+wrapper.isEven());
System.out.println("Is Odd ? "+wrapper.isOdd());

class IntWrapper
{
    private int x;
    public IntWrapper(int x)
    {
         this.x = x;
    }

    public boolen isEven()
    {
         return x%2==0;
    }

    public boolean isOdd()
    {
         return !isEven();
    }
}
```